# Agregar 0 a la izquierda - PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5

Mi problema es el siguiente: A la hora de crear un nuevo cliente, necesito que en la base de datos se guarden 6 dígitos, comenzando con `000001`. El problema es que al guardarlo, en `MySQL` me guarda solo el 1 y necesito que me guarde los 6 dígitos.

El campo `numero_tarjeta` de la tabla cliente es el que necesito que se guarde con los 6 dígitos.

Este es el controlador para agregar un nuevo cliente:

```
public function create()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $nombre = $user->name;

        //obtenemos todas las categorias para cargar el combobox
        $cliente = Cliente::all();
        return view('cliente.crearCliente',['nombre'=>$nombre,'titulo'=>'Crear Cliente']);
    }



    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        ///validamos los campos enviados
        $validator =  Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'nombre' => 'required|min:3|regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u',
            'apellido' => 'required|min:3|regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u',
            'dni' => 'required|min:7|max:8',
            'fecha_nacimiento' => 'date_format:d/m/Y',
            'celular' => 'min:9',
            'email' => 'email',
            'cantidad_puntos' => 'required|numeric',
            'numero_tarjeta' => 'required'
        ]);

        $numero_tarjeta = $request->input('numero_tarjeta');

        //si falla la validacion, redireccionamos con los errores
        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            $errors = $validator->errors();
            $errors =  json_decode($errors);

            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => $errors
            ], 422);
        } else{
            //si no falla la validacion, se carga el cliente en la BD e informamos

            //cambiamos el formato de la fecha
            $fecha_nacimiento = $date = str_replace('/', '-', $request->input('fecha_nacimiento'));
            $request->merge(array('fecha_nacimiento' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha_nacimiento))));
            //$request->merge(array('fecha_nacimiento' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->input('fecha_nacimiento')))));

            $numero_tarjeta = LPAD('numero_tarjeta',6,'0');


            //guardar los datos
            $cliente = New Cliente();
            $cliente->create($request->all());

            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'record updated'
            ], 200);
        }
    }
```

Y mi tabla cliente es la siguiente:

```
Schema::create('clientes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->string('apellido');
            $table->string('dni');
            $table->date('fecha_nacimiento');
            $table->string('celular');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->integer('cantidad_puntos');
            $table->integer('numero_tarjeta')->unique();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numero_de_tarjeta` es un campo entero que necesitas desplegar como un string. Algo como

```
$numero_de_tarjeta_texto = str_pad($number,6,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Si el problema como bien describes lo tienes en el campo de tu table clientes de la base de datos entonces solo debes de alterar el campo de la tabla, suponiendo que es MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE `clientes` CHANGE `numero_tarjeta ` `numero_tarjeta ` INT(6) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

De otra forma, si no quieres modificar el campo, puedes crear un mutador del campo numero_tarjeta en el modelo así:

```
public function getNumeroTarjetaAttribute() {
  return sprintf("%05d", $this->attributes['numero_tarjeta']);
}
```